# How to fix Too many authentication failures for root with having .ssh/config file

Tags: linux, ssh

I have `~/.ssh/config` file like this and I can SSH to my know and defined hosts with no problem:

```
Host usa
  User root
  HostName IP_1
  IdentityFile /home/saeed/.ssh/usa
  Port PORT

Host file
  User root
  HostName IP_2
  IdentityFile /home/saeed/.ssh/file
```

Whenever I try to SSH to a new and undefined host in `config` file, I get this error:

```
Received disconnect from IP port PORT:2: Too many authentication failures for root
Disconnected from IP port PORT
```

I know I can fix it by either adding it to `config` file, or using:

```
ssh root@IP -pPORT -o IdentitiesOnly=yes
```

But there are many customers that I just SSH to their servers one time and there is no need to add them to `config` file.

Are there any methods or ways to use SSH like before? I mean that there should be no need to either **add to `config` file** or use **-o IdentitiesOnly=yes** option.

Comment: add "Host *" . Reference: https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/

Comment: @SharuzzamanAhmatRaslan I have added `Host * User root` to the top, but it still not working for hosts not there. I only can ssh to `ssh root@one_of_defined_ips`